# Почему PageSpeed ругается на кеш?

Tags: .htaccess, оптимизация, кэширование, оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights

Использую шаблон с оптимизацией загрузки страницы, с асинхронной загрузкой стилей и настроенным .htaccess.

Но вот PageSpeed начинает ругаться что не указан срок действия у файлов на сервере и что css мешает загрузке страницы .

[PageSpeed проекта](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserjo.h1n.ru%2Fdublinv2%2F&tab=mobile)

Код .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>

# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"

# Cache Images
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"

# Cache Fonts
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"

# Cache other content types (Flash, CSS, JS, HTML, XML)
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

</ifModule>
```

загрузка стилей

```
// Load CSS Start
    script loadCSS( "css/clear.min.css?", false, "all" );
    script loadCSS( "css/owl.carousel.min.css?", false, "all" );
    script loadCSS( "css/font.css?", false, "all" );
    script loadCSS( "css/header.min.css?ver=1.0.0", false, "all" );
    script loadCSS( "css/main.min.css?ver=1.0.0", false, "all" );
    // Load CSS End

    // Load CSS Compiled without JS
    noscript
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/main.min.css')
```

и скрипт загрузки css

```
  function (e) {
    "use strict";

    function t(e, t, n) {
        e.addEventListener ? e.addEventListener(t, n, !1) : e.attachEvent && e.attachEvent("on" + t, n)
    }

    function n(t, n) {
        return e.localStorage && localStorage[t + "_content"] && localStorage[t + "_file"] === n
    }

    function a(t, a) {
        if (e.localStorage && e.XMLHttpRequest) n(t, a) ? o(localStorage[t + "_content"]) : l(t, a);
        else {
            var s = r.createElement("link");
            s.href = a, s.id = t, s.rel = "stylesheet", s.type = "text/css", r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s), r.cookie = t
        }
    }

    function l(e, t) {
        var n = new XMLHttpRequest;
        n.open("GET", t, !0), n.onreadystatechange = function () {
            4 === n.readyState && 200 === n.status && (o(n.responseText), localStorage[e + "_content"] = n.responseText, localStorage[e + "_file"] = t)
        }, n.send()
    }

    function o(e) {
        var t = r.createElement("style");
        t.setAttribute("type", "text/css"), r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t), t.styleSheet ? t.styleSheet.cssText = e : t.innerHTML = e
    }
    var r = e.document;
    e.loadCSS = function (e, t, n) {
        var a, l = r.createElement("link");
        if (t) a = t;
        else {
            var o;
            o = r.querySelectorAll ? r.querySelectorAll("style,link[rel=stylesheet],script") : (r.body || r.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).childNodes, a = o[o.length - 1]
        }
        var s = r.styleSheets;
        l.rel = "stylesheet", l.href = e, l.media = "only x", a.parentNode.insertBefore(l, t ? a : a.nextSibling);
        var c = function (e) {
            for (var t = l.href, n = s.length; n--;)
                if (s[n].href === t) return e();
            setTimeout(function () {
                c(e)
            })
        };
        return l.onloadcssdefined = c, c(function () {
            l.media = n || "all"
        }), l
    }, e.loadLocalStorageCSS = function (l, o) {
        n(l, o) || r.cookie.indexOf(l) > -1 ? a(l, o) : t(e, "load", function () {
            a(l, o)
        })
    }
}(this);
```

Comment: У вас там nginx отвечает, а не Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге все оказалось банально просто, в настройках хоста была отключена настройка кэширования для вложенных папок.

Answer (score 2):

Я использую следующую версию htacces Apache:

```css
FileETag none
<FilesMatch "^\.htaccess">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(rdf|js|css||png|jpeg|html)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
   ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Разумеется там надо редактировать расширения ваших файлов и изображений. **[Документация Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)** ++ **[модули предлагаемые Гугл](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/)** для оптимизации скорости загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

1. PageSpeed Tools просит CSS в конец страницы поставить
2. Вы для модуля expires прописали директивы, а Nginx, что в нем?

Comment: Вроде как css он предлагает асинхронно загружать. 
Nginx не трогал, только htaccess

Comment: .htaccess для сервера - apache. Nginx - для фронтренда, и по заголовкам ответа в консоли, .png от nginx ответ приходит.

Comment: Либо у вас сервер не apache, либо nginx не дает дальше запросу пройти, кеширует согласно своим конфигам.

Comment: Сравните запросы с ответами в консоли браузера.

Comment: Судя по анализаторам я нашел у себя информацию только про  Nginx

Comment: Если есть доступ к серверу - меняйте конфиг nginx(если не ошибаюсь, используется для всего сервера, для отдельного проекта его изменить нельзя). Либо меняйте хостинг. .htaccess здесь бесполезен.